# I can't use setContent in TinyMCE in full screen mode

Tags: jquery, tinymce

While TinyMCE in full screen mode i cant set content inside tinymce

I can set content while normally using TinyMCE but once in full screen mode I can't set content in TinyMCE.

I tried:

```
tinyMCE.getInstanceById("textarea_id").setContent('this is a sample content');
tinyMCE.get('textarea_id').setContent('this is a sample content');
```

I read inside fullscreen plugin they used some thing like this:

`fullscreenEditor.setContent`

To fetch content

I need to know how to check TinyMCE in fullscreen or not and how to set content inside TinyMCE in fullscreen mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adress the tinymce instance differently:

```
var new_content = "xyz";
tinymce.get('mce_fullscreen').setContent(new_content);
```